# Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT'

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, proc-open

I am running the following `proc_open` function. When the page is loaded, I get the error:

```
Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT'`
```

How should I set `STDOUT` and `STSDERR` correctly?

**PHP Snippet**

```
$cmd = 'psql -p 5432 -d nominatim';

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => STDOUT,  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => STDERR // stderr is a file to write to
);

$pipes = null;

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

---

### Update

```
<?php

    $cmd = 'psql -p 5432 -d nominatim';

    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
        2 => array('pipe', 'a') // stderr
    );

    $pipes = null;

    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

?>
```

When I `chmod 755 test.php` and run `./test.php` in the command line (CentOS), I get the error output:

```
: No such file or directory
: command not found
./test.php: line 3: =: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
./test.php: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'/test.php: line 5: `   $descriptorspec = array(
```

This is puzzling, `=` is not a command?

---

### Update 2

```
#!/usr/bin/php <?php

    $cmd = 'psql -p 5432 -d nominatim';

    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin
        1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
        2 => array('pipe', 'a') // stderr
    );

    $pipes = null;

    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

?>
```

I get the output:

```
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.16
Content-type: text/html

No input file specified.
```

Comment: Maybe `php://stdout` and `php://stderr` would work?

Comment: I tried that and had the error `fopen() [function.fopen]: Invalid php:// URL specified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use :

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin
    1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
    2 => array('pipe', 'a') // stderr
);
```

instead

Have a look to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Comment: I tried that on the command line and updated the original post with the error msg.

Comment: add #!/usr/bin/php at the very top of your file, or instead of typing ./test.php use php test.php

Comment: do not put #!/usr/bin/php <?php in the same line, <?php must be under #!/usr/bin/php